# Can I package a single text file as a text file in a maven repo?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I have a single configuration file which I would like to include as a dependency in a maven pom.xml.  I want to keep around several versions of this, and have it appear in the classpath.  I realize I could wrap it in a jar, but others in my team would like to easily inspect its contents.  Looking at the  types allowed in the pom.xml, I only see things like pom, jar, war, ear, ...  Basically just archives of some sort.  So I'm wondering what the pom.xml might look like to package a single file.  I would imaging the maven artifacts on inspecting the server to be something like

```
myconfig-0.0.1.cfg
myconfig-0.0.1.cfg.md5
myconfig-0.0.1.cfg.sha1
myconfig-0.0.1.pom
myconfig-0.0.1.pom.md5
myconfig-0.0.1.pom.sha1
```

So is this possible?  What would the pom.xml look like?

Answer (score 3):

I would wrap the configuration file in a jar and use the [Dependency](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) plugin to  **[`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html)** the jar during the **`generate-resources`** phase (see the [Unpacking specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) example). This would allow to version it easily, to add it as dependency easily, and to inspect it easily.

Answer (score 1):

See this discussion, specifically on using the maven-install plugin to define an installable artifact:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4245890/2491903