# maven : deploy artifact file name

Tags: maven, deployment, names

Hi : Im finding that maven deploys by default change the file name to match the version+artifact id.  For example

Deploying a jar file, with artifact=A and version=V-0.1 will result in a jar file named AV-0.1.jar.

Is there a way to change the default name of the jar file in the deployment, so that it doesnt concatenate these feilds or to specify the final deployed jar name explicitly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact) question.

Answer (score 8):

Complex answer to that: Yes

It is a bit tricky and you need to be careful, as the pom won't get re-written. So only the maven remote repository (artifactory, or nexus) will put it into the correct folder structure.

If you overwrite the deploy-file goal in the maven deploy goal, you can overwrite the parameters: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html

One example which would always post version 4.5.1 to nexus would look like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <repositoryId>nexus-site</repositoryId>
                        <url>http://nexus.some.where/nexus-2/content/repositories/releases</url>
                        <file>${build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</file>
                        <generatePom>false</generatePom>
                        <pomFile>pom.xml</pomFile>
                        <version>4.5.1</version>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

(and before someone asks, one reason to do something like this is to make builds more CI friendly. in CI everything is just a build number, there is not really a "build a release", every checkin does yield a production-ready artifact. So by replacing 4.5.1 with `${BUILD_NUMBER}` will leave you with many many releases in your artifact storage ...)

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for this for a while now! Only problem I got left is that I use `maven-shade-plugin`. Now I deploy two files to my target system: The old one with the timestamp and the new that comes from your solution up there ^^

Comment: @StefanFalk The `shadedArtifactAttached` and `shadedClassifierName` options of the maven shade plugin may help you. See this example: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/attached-artifact.html

Comment: that's a nice solution but how do i handle this when i need to take care about snapshot repository and release repository?

Answer (score 3):

Using curl command line it seems to be possible to feed Nexus with whatever you want.

```
curl -u<deploymentUser>:<deploymentPassword> --upload-file <someLocalFile> -v http://<nexusServerDNSName>/nexus/content/repositories/<repoPath>/<fileName>
```

- *deploymentUser* and *deploymentPassword* should be taken from ~/.m2/settings.xml.
- *someLocalFile* is the file you want to deploy (absolute path)
- *fileName* is an arbitrary name you want to see in the remote repository (you must not follow any naming convension here)

For me it perfectly worked. What is great is that it works without pom.xml.

*Update*: this answer might be useful for the one who searches how to bypass Maven concept and deploy an arbitrary named file to Nexus. If the question is how to do it using namely Maven, then I would agree with the answer "Not possible".

Comment: This helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer to that is: No.

The problem behind it is if you would change the naming schema it will not be possible to find artifacts in a repository. That's the reason having a fixed naming schema.

Answer (score 1):

> mvn deploy:deploy-file -DartifactId=AAA -Dversion=VVV
>   -Dpackaging=jar

The command above will place the file in the following structure.

```
AAA
-VVV
--AAA_VVV.jar
```

If you just want to make the name of the created file different between consecutive pushes to the artifactory, you can use -Dpackaging parameter. ie. Set the value to the current timestamp

> mvn deploy:deploy-file -DartifactId=AAA -Dversion=VVV
>   -Dpackaging=2017_01_31_01_37.jar

```
AAA
-VVV
--AAA_VVV.jar
--AAA_VVV2017_01_31_01_37.jar
```

Comment: For my snapshot version the dot after the unique version (date) remains and the packaging value is appended to the dot. Is there any way to remove the dot. I currently get: AAA_VVV.2017_01_31_01_37.jar but I want to remove the dot after VVV.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very simple way to solve this problem

```
mvn versions:set "-DnewVersion=$buildNumber"
```

this command will change the whole project's pom.xml file's "version" tag.
I am using it in a release pipeline in a virtual environment. It won't change our code but can achieve the goal.