# How to include package.jar with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I used maven and maven-jar-plugin and maven-assembly-plugin to build a zip of my project including the projects jar and its dependencies.

This is the plugin configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>MyMainClass</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And this is the assembly.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <includes>${project.build.finalName}</includes>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/lib/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

I try to include the jar created by the maven-jar-plugin using `<fileSet><includes>${project.build.finalName}</includes>...`. But this throws an error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (default) on project tbdb-core: Error reading assemblies: Error reading descriptor: src/main/assembly/assembly.xml: expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...<fileSet>\r\n\t\t\t<includes>${project.build.finalName}</... @10:42) -> [Help 1]
```

Omitting the `fileset` entry, I get an zip only with the dependencies.

How can I include just the jar created by the maven-jar-plugin? TIA!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
<fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.jar</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
```

Please refer to [Guide to creating assemblies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-assemblies.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. That works! Is it not a litty bit risky, because it may include other jar, older versions or something like that. Is there any option to get the correct jar-name?

Comment: you can specify the complete jar name instead of *.jar, by default it is  ${project.build.finalName}.jar, so you can specify <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact to know how to change your jar name.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `${project.build.finalName}` (see above) but I missed the extension ... ;)