# maven dependency - 3 projects and 1 framework project dependency not be including

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Eclipse - Neon
Maven
Java
archetype - 4 projects

Hi, I generated an maven archetype with 4 projects ?

```
============================================================
 - framework (packaging ejb)
 - bulk (kind of packaging : pom) it has 3 modules.
   - bulk_ear
   - bulk_ejb
   - bulk_web

 - bulke_ear (packaging ear)
 - bulk_ejb  (packaging ejb) - jpa...
 - bulk_web  (packaging war)
===========================================================
```

I would like to add the framework.jar as dependency to be used on the bulk_web and bulk_ejb projects

Would you please help me to do that. because I tried but with no success

My tries :

1. I added the framework dependency on bulk
2. I added the framework dependency on bulk_ear

But when I Maven install, the framework.jar does not packaged to ear.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal "provided" means that the jar is provided by you manually or by the including framwork. Also if you want to package your artifacts with other libs you should have a look at the maven assembly plugin.
[How to include package.jar with maven-assembly-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126406/how-to-include-package-jar-with-maven-assembly-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change maven `scope` to `compile`:

> Compile means that you need the JAR for compiling and running the app. For a web application, as an example, the JAR will be placed in the WEB-INF/lib directory.
>
> Provided means that you need the JAR for compiling, but at run time there is already a JAR provided by the environment so you don't need it packaged with your app. For a web app, this means that the JAR file will not be placed into the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: What project must I add the <scope>compile> ?

Comment: if you want `framework.jar` be part of `ear`, then define `framework` as`compile` scope

Comment: When I add compile in bulk-ear, I got compilation error because in my persistence.xml there is a class named Parameter that is created on the framework project