# Deploying a Maven version to Github using Travis CI

Tags: maven, deployment, github, travis-ci

I successfully managed to deploy a JAR from a maven project to Github using tags. However, current configuration assumes that the file name of the JAR always stays the same, which it doesn't. When I do a new release this will change accordingly so deployment will fail.

Is there a way I can use kind of wildcards in the YAML file? From what I found here on Stackoverflow and on the web, wildcards are not supported in YAML. I couldn't find another hack for doing this without manipulating the .travis.yml file itself, which I would like to avoid.

The version string is available in `pom.xml`.

Current .travis.yml:

```
language: java
jdk:
- openjdk7

deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: asfdsdflkjsdflkj...
  file: target/helloci-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  on:
    repo: ktk/helloci
    all_branches: true
    tags: true
```

I could surely script that somehow but then Travis CI would change its own configuration file and I'm not sure if this a) will work and b) is a good idea.

Repo I'm playing with: https://github.com/ktk/helloci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcards are supported now, I run this setup:

```
before_deploy:
  - "mvn -DskipTests package"
  - export FOO=$(ls target/foo-version-*.jar)

deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: yep
  file: "${FOO}"
```

Answer (score 9):

A work around is to have maven generate the file using a fixed name, this can be done with

```
<build>
    <finalName>helloci</finalName>
</build>
```

However you probably want to keep the name as per maven conventions if you're not building on travis-ci. You can achieve this by adding the following to your pom:

```
<properties>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
</properties>
<build>
    <finalName>${finalName}</finalName>
```

And passing `-DfinalName=helloci` when executing maven by adding the following 2 lines to your `.travis.yml` file:

```
before_install: mvn install -DskipTests=true -DfinalName=helloci
install: mvn test
```

You might also want to add the tag name to the name of the generated file. This can be achieved with:

```
before_install: mvn install -DskipTests=true -DfinalName=helloci-$TRAVIS_TAG
deploy:
  file: target/helloci-$TRAVIS_TAG.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, wildcard patterns don't work at the moment, but we'll have a look into making that possible on Travis CI.