# Custom maven-archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I am creating a custom maven archetype. I have defined the archetype.xml file under the src/main/resources/META-INF/maven. I also have included the default Java classes under the src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java. However I am not sure as to how can I parameterize the package names for the Java classes when the actual maven project gets generated. The basic [maven guide to creating archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) does not seem to have details around this. Any ideas as to how this can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out. You have to include the statement:

> package ${packageName};

in the java classes. This ensures that the classess get generated with the right package information.

Comment: Are you sure of this ${packageName}? Just today have created an archetype and used ${package} instead, so I'm doubtful about another property name instead. I tested mine with interactive archetype generation.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should specify you finalName. This can be done via this code in pom.xml
Its described here : [MAVEN](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#finalName)
also [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact) you can fined some hints.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
         <finalName>YourNameOfJar</finalName>                   
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough, I was referring to java packages (as in java classes belonging to packages). How can this be specified in the .java files (located under src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java) ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you would need to call ${package} but you should not go too far with this, top level package is the limit.

So, having some subpackages, you would put all files in your top directory, and use

```
package ${package};
```

or

```
package ${package}.subpackage;
```

in them.

Have never created archetypes with more than top package though.

Comment: Thats not correct. You can add subpackages in your top directory. The file in the subpackage has to be in the `src/main/java/subpackage/Yourclass.java` folder and needs this package declaration: `package ${package}.subpackage;`

Comment: Will test after vacation. I have a feeling back then it was like I described, but that's quite some time ago and it's just the feeling now. So, will check. Thanks.