# Get and use the final build names of Maven modules

Tags: java, maven

I have a parent Maven project, which has two modules a `main` starting one and a `lib`. I am using the exec plugin in the parent project, and I would like to be able to fire up the already packaged `main` module like so:

```
java -jar <MAIN_MODULE_TARGET_DIR>/<MAIN_MODULE_TARGET_NAME>.jar
```

The problem is that I could not find appropriate properties anywhere. I have been looking for `${main.build.finalName}` or `${modules.main.build.finalName}`, but nothing like that exists. The only matching properties are related to the current project itself i.e. `${project.build.finalName}`

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14490656/1858327) but in the modules' poms instead of the parent's?

Comment: Well, the reason is that one of the modules should actually work as a java agent for the other. Instead of letting the modules explicitly know about this, I'd like to encapsulate this knowledge only in the parent.