# Oracle weblogic 12c + local EJB lookup

Tags: ejb, weblogic, local, lookup

```
I have a an ear file to be deployed on weblogic 12c.

I have following project structure :
1) prop-application which is an .ear file
2) prop-service which is a .jar file
3) prop-framework which is a .jar file

All are maven project. 
 - prop-service contains prop-framework as one of its maven dependency. 
 - prop-application which is an ear contains prop-service

so we can say : prop-application.ear = prop-service.jar + prop-framework.jar
                prop-service.jar = more java codes + prop-framework.jar

Now there is a class in prop-framework as :

@Stateless(name = "ServiceCallerBean")
public class ServiceCallerBean implements ServiceCaller

@Local
public interface ServiceCaller

Requirement :
Now i want to lookup(call) this EJB from a from a class in *prop-service* i.e a local look. The point here is to note that prop-service.jar contains prop-framework.jar

Following is the jndi names generated by weblogic 12c server :
java:global/ProposalEngine/prop-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ServiceCallerBean.> 
java:module/ServiceCallerBean.> 
java:app/prop-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ServiceCallerBean.> 
java:global/ProposalEngine/prop-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ServiceCallerBean!com.db.serviceframework.ejb.ServiceCaller.> 
java:app/prop-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ServiceCallerBean!com.db.serviceframework.ejb.ServiceCaller.> 
java:module/ServiceCallerBean!com.db.serviceframework.ejb.ServiceCaller.> 

I can't use those jndi names which contains jar version(eg 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT) because jar version will keep on changing. But if i use any of the jndi names like java:module/ServiceCallerBean , then there lookup fails with javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup error

I have tried even :
@EJB
ServiceCaller serviceCaller
```

in the required class in prop-service but serviceCaller comes out to be null here. Searched on this issue and found that we can use @EJB in only container managed classes, not in simple java class.

I have tried everything but noting seems to be working. So plz help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/ejb-31-global-jndi-access.html) contains a nice explanation of where the JNDI addresses come from.  The `prop-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` entry is taken from the name of the JAR or WAR, so you can use the Maven JAR plugin to change the `final name` of your JAR you should be able to remove the version number, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact).