# How to skip version in jar generated by maven-jar-plugin and clasifier

Tags: maven

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>client</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>client</classifier>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/com.service/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>

                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I want the version to be appended to end of the jar.Right now it is building jar like ship-service-0.1-client.jar,I want it like ship-service-client-0.1.jar and i need to add it as dependency in another project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling maven final name of jar artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact)

Comment: A classifiier sounds like a design flaw. You should make a separate maven module of the classifier part...The naming is `ship-service-0.1-client.jar` which you can't change if this is a classifer artifact.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
<build>
    <finalName>FinalNameOfYourProyect</finalName>
</build>
```

check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact)

Comment: If there is already an answered question in SO, don't give another one. Flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: This will only change the name in `target` folder but will not change the name which is deployed. Simply cause it can't be renamed.