# How to generate maven artifact with jenkins build number

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-2, pom.xml, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I'm trying associate maven artifacts name with build number.
ex: sample.1.0.0-snapshot.ear into sample.1.0.0-snapshot.buildnumber.ear

I have tried maven-buildnumber plugin but still no luck.

could anyone help me to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Versions Maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html) by executing following command before any other maven targets after clean.

mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=sample.1.0.0-snapshot.$BUILD_NUMBER

Comment: the above command is changing the pom version not the name of the artifacts

Comment: Did you tried the generate artifact and what was the final artifact name you are getting after executing.

Comment: same name which was generating before

Comment: Is there any reference of "finalName" used in pom.xml. If possible try to provide us the full pom.

Comment: This post is also talking about the handling the [final artifact names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact).

Comment: this is generating artifacts in .m2 repo not in target. i have not mentioned any finalName reference in pom.xml

Comment: Is it not generating any artifacts in target folder

Comment: its gerenating artifacts but not in the "sample.1.0.0-snapshot.buildnumber.ear" format

Comment: Try adding finalName in pom. and see how it is behaving.

Comment: it is creating the sample.1.0.0-snapshot.buildnumber.ear in .m2 but not in target

Comment: What configuration you did in Jenkins, provide a screenshot of the build step