# Using maven package in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have Java Maven project in Eclipse. When I do `maven build` and set goal to `package` maven builds jar file with name `my-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. I need package to be always constant name since I put it system that starts it with script. `my-project.jar` would be fine. How to achieve that?

How to ask maven to put all jar libraries my project is using into `my-project.jar`?

How to ask maven to place `my-project.jar` into particular folder `target/ready_release`. Currently maven puts jar into `target` folder. How to ask maven copy all libraries and configuration files project is using into this folder too.

Maybe I'm mistaking and all these jobs should be done under some other maven goal or any other operation?

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.aaa.rfid.scaleandlabel</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <organization>
    <name>aaa</name>
    <url>www.aaa.lt</url>
  </organization>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scream3r</groupId>
        <artifactId>jssc</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling maven final name of jar artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the name of the package by configuring the jar plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>ready_release/my-project</finalName>                   
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will create the jar file at `<project-root>/target/ready_release/jar-name.jar` and every subsequent build will overwrite it.

Comment: Where I can find configuration file? Is it pom.xml?

Comment: @vico yes, that snippet goes under `<build><plugins>` in your pom.xml file

Comment: Currenly I don't have `build` section at all. Please find my pom.xml in question body. Why? How Eclipse is building? Should I manually add `build` section?

Comment: @vico Just add the build section. What you're having now is based on default configuration. You just have to customize it