# How to deploy .war file with fixed path in Tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

My .war file is created with a version in it. For example:
myproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war

For next version it would be second version :
myproject-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war

and so on.

Now if I deploy to tomcat the path would change with every new version as Tomcat just takes the filename as the context path.

Of course this is not acceptable as the path should be fixed.

So I already tried to create a context.xml file in META-INF folder and set path there , but did not help.

What else could I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can include a context version in your war's file name by using "##" as delimiter, see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming

It will be stripped on deployment, leaving you with the same context path as before.

Comment: ## almost works . But myproject-SNAPSHOT  becomes myproject-.war  So I still have to get rid of the dash

Comment: I didn't know about this! Definitely more elegant than my answer.

Comment: @Stomf This is where Tomcat's manager app extracts its "Version" column from. Haven't seen much usage of it anyway.

Comment: How can I get rid of dash in filename ??

Comment: @Toni26 Not sure, but it should be possible using <build><finalName>, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/

Comment: hm. no idea so far.

Comment: this worked .   <finalName>${project.name}##${project.version}</finalName>

Comment: Well done. I'm happy to see you could solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the war file before deploying.

Or, if you're using the api from the manager app to deploy, set the path parameter

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/foo
```

Reference: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/manager-howto.html